# How to make an app to use dedicated gpu

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu

I have two NVIDIA cards GTX 1060 and GTX 650. Sometimes one of them mines. Is it possible to make apps like Chrome, VS Code, etc. launch on the second card?
I saw an option in NVIDIA driver to select GPU for CUDA and 3D operations. But nothing changes after selection.[image]

Comment: Maybe [this](https://superuser.com/a/1030002/321990) will help you?

Comment: I did exactly the same thing. It doesn't work.